# PrimeNG not working with angular2 cli?

Tags: angular, primeng

Trying to work with angular2 cli and PrimeNG but facing error :

> http://localhost:4200/vendor/primeng/primeng 404 (Not Found)

What I have done so far :

- `npm install primeng`
- In `angular-cli-build.js` file add path like this :-

  ```
    (...)
    'primeng/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
    (...)
  ```
- and using in my component like this:-

  ```
   import {Calendar} from 'primeng/primeng';
  ```

but getting error PrimeNG not found.

Should I have to do anything else to make this working ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi You need to add the reference of  `primeng` into the config

```
    var  map = {
    ...
    'primeng' :            'primeng/primeng'
    ...
 };

  //packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    ...
    'primeng' :            {main : "<path of its js file>", defaultExtension : "js"}
    ...
  };

var config = {
    // DEMO ONLY! REAL CODE SHOULD NOT TRANSPILE IN THE BROWSER
    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
      tsconfig: true
    },
    meta: {
      'typescript': {
        "exports": "ts"
      }
    },
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: wooo its working fine, thanks , could you explain bit more about this ?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue and brand new to angular 2. Which config are we talking about here, which file to be more exact?

Comment: I am talking about systemjs.config.js file

Comment: Where can I find this file @HardipsinhJadeja ?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is for System.js
Im also using primeNG with angular cli
and i installed it as a dependency by typing

```
npm install --save primeng
```

Later in appModule.ts make sure you have the folloing imports

```
import {ChartModule}  from 'primeng/primeng';
import {DialogModule}  from 'primeng/primeng';
```

and in the @NgModule array of imports, add them as well as shown

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ChartModule,
    DialogModule,
    Ng2PaginationModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

- npm install primeng --save
- npm install primeicons --save

run these two commands

- npm install @angular/animations --save

install animations also and then import the modules whatever we want to import in module.ts